# AsyncTask Inside A Service Populating A ListView

Tags: php, android, listview, service, android-asynctask

I've got this piece of code which I'm going to provide below. It posts the users ID, Latitude and Longitude which in php updates the current users lat and long and then executes a query which retrieves an array of users which are within a certain area around you. (Retrieves the age, name..) So this populates a listView, but the query has to be manually executed, via refresh or upon opening the activity. However I have a LocationService, and in it, it has a onLocationChanged() which updates when the location of the user changes. I need my query/asynctask to execute every time the location changes and then populate my listView in my Activity. Any suggestions/code examples.

This is the code inside my activity which calls an async task:

```
private void startQueryView() {
    // show progress dialog
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    LocalDatabase localDatabase = new LocalDatabase(this);
    User user = localDatabase.getLoggedInUser();
    String url = ServerRequests.SERVER_ADDRESS + "CombinedQuery.php";
    UserFetchData task = new UserFetchData(this, user.latitude, user.longitude, user.id);
    task.execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<UserQueryData> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if (dialog != null) dialog.dismiss();
    // create new adapter
    final UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(this, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final int userId = adapter.getItem(position).getId();

            int i;
            new DownloadImage(LocationSearch.this, userId + "_Profile").execute();

            for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {

                new DownloadImage(LocationSearch.this, userId + "_Image" + Integer.toString(i)).execute();

            }


            ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(LocationSearch.this);
            serverRequests.fetchDifUserDataInBackground(userId, new GetDifUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(DifUser returnedDifUser) {

                    if (returnedDifUser == null) {
                        String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                        File file = new File(dir, userId + "_Profile.JPG");
                        boolean deleted = file.delete();
                        if (deleted) {
                            Log.d("THIS", "******************ProfileDeleted***********");
                        }

                        int i;
                        for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
                            String dir2 = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                            File file2 = new File(dir2, userId + "_Image" + Integer.toString(i) + ".JPG");
                            boolean deleted2 = file2.delete();
                            if (deleted2) {
                                Log.d("THIS", "******************Image" + Integer.toString(i) + "***********");
                            }

                        }

                        Toast.makeText(LocationSearch.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {


                        Intent userIdIntent = new Intent(LocationSearch.this, UserProfileOpened.class);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putInt("userId", userId);
                        editor.commit();
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("name", returnedDifUser.name);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("city", returnedDifUser.city);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("age", returnedDifUser.age);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("gender", returnedDifUser.gender);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("places", returnedDifUser.places);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("relationship", returnedDifUser.relationship);
                        userIdIntent.putExtra("facebook", returnedDifUser.facebook);
                        startActivity(userIdIntent);


                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if (dialog != null) dialog.dismiss();
    // show failure message
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If you need anything more, please say it and I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Give `Intent`s a shot.

Make an `Intent` action like so:

`public static String QUERY = "com.package.QUERY";`

Then extend `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity:

```
private class QueryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void OnReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    startQueryView(); /*running your query when receiving an Intent*/
  }
}
```

Then in your activity `OnCreate()` method, set up a listener:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(QUERY);
receiver = new QueryReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver,filter); /* registering the receiver to receive only intents with the action QUERY */
```

Finally, in the location listener, shoot off an `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(QUERY);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

<strike>You should take a look at the documentation for `LocationListener`.</strike>

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Using this, you'll know whenever your user's lat/long changes!

Comment: I know when my lat/long changes, what I need help with has to do with the action which happens after it changes. Which involves running an asynctask within the Service so that from there the data which is retrieved from the database populates the listView within the Activity where the service was started.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you revise your question and perhaps point out what the problem is?

Comment: "However I have a LocationService, and in it, it has a onLocationChanged() which updates when the location of the user changes. My query/asynctask to execute every time the location changes and then populate my listView in my Activity." I thought this was clear enough. The code which I provided is in my Activity, but i want it in my Service in the onLocationChanged() so that the query is executed every time the location of the user changes. Which will then and the same time populate my listView with the new data.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I updated my answer to something that should fix your problem without moving the code around.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I needed, working perfectly, thank you.